# console.log() not called when modal window is opened

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal which works as expected, but I want to execute a `console.log()` when it's launched. I don't see the message.

My code in `main.js`:

```
$("#myModal").on("shown", function(event){
    modalBox.modal('show');
    $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
       width: 'auto',
       height: 'auto',
       maxheight: '100%'
    }); 
   $("a#showUser").on('click',function(evt)
   {
        console.log("hello!!"); 
   });
});
```

My anchor is:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" id="showUser" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Alta usuario</a>
```

When I press the anchor the modal appears.

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">{% block modal_title %}{% endblock modal_title %}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="alert hidden" id="modal-alert"></div>
                        <div id="modal-body-content">
                            {% block modal_body %} {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        {% block modal_footer %} {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

But I don't see the `console.log()` message.

Comment: Use the `$("a#showUser").on('click'` outside the `$("#myModal").on("shown"`. You are listening to the click event inside the modal after it has opened and that's why you don't get the message. Use as it 2 separate events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `click` function out the modal `shonw` function

```
$("#myModal").on("shown", function(event){
    modalBox.modal('show');
    $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
       width: 'auto',
       height: 'auto',
       maxheight: '100%'
    }); 
});

$("a#showUser").on('click',function(evt){
    console.log("hello!!"); 
});
```

Comment: that's it. good catch. but still i feel about `modalBox` it could produce error if not defined.